# What is the corresponding transfer function between r and y?

Tags: control-engineering

[image]

What is the corresponding transfer function between r and y??

I have tried
$$
\frac{( \frac{k_i}{s}+k_p+k_d\ s )\times P(s)}{1-(-1)(\frac{k_i}{s}+k_p+k_d\ s)\times P(s)}
$$

Comment: What have you worked out so far ? Please [edit] the steps you have already worked out into the question. Have you tried block diagram reduction methods ? Are you familiar with the feedback formula $\frac{G}{1+GH}$ ? Please [edit] all such details into the question.

Comment: i have tried( ki/s+kp+kds)*p(s)/1-(-1)(ki/s+kp+kds)*p(s)

Comment: Is the diagram drawn correctly ? Do the input lines to `Kp` and `Kd` come from the summing junction or the `-1` block ? If it comes from the `-1` block, it is somewhat suspicious. I think your answer is correct only if the input to the `Kp` and `Kd` are same as the input given to `Ki`. Otherwise, you can't add those terms. If I carefully look at the input lines to `Kp` and `Kd`, I can see that the lines are **darker** leading to the summing block. Hmmm.... suspicious....

Comment: Also, what are **signs** to the summing blocks ? are all positive ?

Comment: all positive ..i have the answer but i dont understand hem  
Gyr=bki/(1+bkd)s^2+(a+bkp)s+bki

Comment: kp and kd not from the summing

Answer (score 1):

If `Kp` and `Kd` are fed from the `-1` block, then you have two loops; an inner loop and an outer loop. Solve the *inner loop* (q to y) using the feedback formula. To solve the inner loop, imagine that the parts shown in pink colour in the diagram below, are not present in the diagram. Replace the result ($\frac{Y(s)}{Q(s)}$) back into the diagram.

Now solve the outer loop $\frac{Y(s)}{R(s)}$ using the result from the inner loop. Use the feedback formula for that also.

I have redrawn the diagram to clearly show the two loops. (Check the redrawn figure for correctness).

[image: redrawn block diagram showing two loops]

Comment: thank you i got the correct answer .. i have a question .how did we become two (-1) blue and red ..??did we move pick off point ??

Comment: If you are familiar with block diagram reduction methods; yes; the pick off point was shifted from output side of the `-1` block to its input side. That results in two copies of the block.

Comment: thank you very much